# Clumps of small multiples of large squares

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

Am I right to be surprised by this big clump of numbers divisible by large squares within a not-so-long interval? If so, should I be surprised because $(1)$ this rarely happens, or because $(2)$ it's something I didn't know about and couldn't have seen coming? Should $19^2\times205$ be given little weight among these because $19^2$ isn't all *that* much bigger than $205,$ and more generally, is the surprising event quantifiable?

\begin{align}
73926 & = 111^2\times6 \\ 73947 & = 157^2\times3 \\ 73960 & = 86^2\times10 \\ 73984 & = 272^2 \\ 73997 & = 31^2\times77 \\ 74005 & = 19^2\times205 \\ 74008 & = 58^2\times22 \\ 74052 & =66^2 \times 17 \\ 74060 & = 46^2\times35 \\ 74088 & = 42^3 \end{align}

Comment: "Not so long interval" is not a problem: if $A_j$ are pairwise coprime large squares, then there exists $N$ such that $A_j|N+j$ for all $j=1,\dots m$ (the Chinese remainder theorem rules). The surprise, if any, is rather that $N$ in your case is not too large, though you don't insist on the full interval, just on a "clamp" here, which helps a bit. So, neither (1), nor (2): I have no doubt that you knew CRT. :-)

Comment: @fedja : ok, So this will eventually happen in some interval no longer than this, and the surprise is that it happened so early, before we even get up to $100\,000.$ So why is $(1)$ wrong? CRT may say that this will happen, but it doesn't seem to say how often it happens, so my word "rarely", may be right.

Comment: @fedja : BTW, standard usage is $A_j\mid N+j,$ coded as `A_j\mid N+j`, not $A_j|N+j,$ coded as `A_j|N+j`. With the former, you can negate it by `A_j\nmid N+j` and it looks like this: $A_j\nmid N+j.$ If you try `A_j\not|N+j` it looks hideous: $A_j\not|N+j.$ $$ \begin{align}  & A_j\mid N+j \\ {} \\ \text{versus } & A_j|N+j \\ {} \\ & A_j\nmid N+j \\ {} \\ \text{versus } & A_n\not|N+j \end{align} $$

Comment: It looks as if (1) this is a commonplace thing, but (2) it is counterintuitive. And therefore some explanation may be in order, if there is one. $$ \begin{align} 18490 & = 43^2 \times 10 \\ 18491 & = 41^2 \times11 \\ 18496 & = 136^2 \\ 18502 & = 29^2\times22 \\ 18513 & = 33^2\times17 \\ 18515 & = 23^2 \times 35 \\ 18522 & = 21^3\times2 \end{align} $$

Comment: $$ \begin{align} 65522 = {} & 181^2\times2 \\ 65533 = {} & 71^2\times13 \\ 65536 = {} & 256^2 \\ 65559 = {} & 41^2\times39 \end{align} $$

Comment: $$\begin{align} 19600 = {} & 140^2 \\ 19602 = {} & 99^2\times2 \\ 19604 = {} & 26^2\times29 \end{align}$$ The two smaller numbers here should not be a surprise since "everybody knows" that $99/70$ is a convergent in the continued-fraction expansion of $\sqrt2,$ but the fact that error in $99/26\approx\sqrt{29/2\,}$ is only a hundredth of what one expects with so small a denominator was unknown to me, and the fact that both involve $99^2\times2$ means these three are an example.